# Swift - splash screen / Launch Screen

Tags: swift, splash-screen, launch-screen

This might be a silly question. I am trying to add launch screen to my app. In Xcode (11.3),I added the imageview in "LaunchScreen.storyboard" and added the image, when i run it in simulator, i notice the top and bottom of screen has default white color. Attached is the screen shot, can any one let me know, how i can add the entire image on screen.

[Launch Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snu55.png)

[Launch Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p77B.png)

Comment: Try setting `ContentMode` of the `UIImageView`  to `scaleAspectFill`

Comment: ContentMode = Scale To Fill, did work for me.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ContentMode of the UIImageView to scaleAspectFill

After doing that you still got the problem so all you need to do set your top and bottom constraints to superview so the white area will not appear.

[image: first image]

after that step you should double click on top space and another thing will open which is also you can see in below image.  [image: second image]
set the top and button constraints like this and you white space will gone.

Comment: ContentMode = Scale To Fill, did work for me.  thanks.